# Потоки в UWP. Создать поток

Tags: c#, многопоточность, xaml, uwp

В NetFramework есть класс Thread для создания потоков. Что есть в UWP???

Answer (score 5):

Ручное создание потоков и ручная работа с ними устарела не только в UWP, но и в десктопном .NET. В UWP не было требования обратной совместимости, и потоки убрали вовсе.

Вы должны использовать TPL: `Task` и async/await.

Пример:

Раньше:

```
int result;

var t = new Thread(() =>
{
    // длинные вычисления
    result = <результат вычислений>;
});
t.Start();
t.Join();
// пользуетесь значением в result
```

Сейчас:

```
int result = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // длинные вычисления
    return <результат вычислений>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Я скажу так: во-первых, конечно же, никуда **потоки выполнения**, aka **threads**, не делись - Windows 10 продолжает классическую парадигму, что бы не придумывали маркетологи и болтуны. Threads есть threads, обзовите их хоть Task-ами, хоть не знаю чем.

В UWP был создан wrapper (даже можно сказать, определенный framework - особенно это заметно из C++) вокруг threads, который был *обозван* *asynchronous programming patterns*.

Но, говоря по простому, "по пацански", разницы... (пропущенное выражение) особой нет. Используйте Task-и, имея в голове, что это - все те-же старые добрые threads (которые поддерживаются, вдобавок, на уровне CPU).

Если у вас будет конкретный вопрос об использовании, буду рад помочь (если google "ниасилит" :) )

Answer (score -1):

Вот пример с ContentDialog и MessageDialog:

```
        async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Вызов MEssageDialog", "Окно диалога");
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ok",CapCap,0));
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancle"));

            UICommand command = await dialog.ShowAsync() as UICommand;               
        }

        private void CapCap(IUICommand command)
        {
            Button_Click_1(btOne,new RoutedEventArgs());
        }

        async private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "Окно диалога",
                Content = "Вызов ContentDialog",
                PrimaryButtonText = "Ok",
                SecondaryButtonText = "Cancle",
            };
            ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync() ;
        }
```

Используется метод ShowAsync() для показа сообщения.